# Did Samsung disable the option to keep apps in memory?

Tags: samsung

In the last few days, I have noticed that the option to lock apps and keep them in memory seems to have been grayed out. This occurred after downloading an OTA update. I am using the SM-9981, with One UI 3.1 and Android 11.

Has Samsung eliminated this option in a recent update? Can it be re-enabled?

Comment: I  only heard stories that [Samsung now aggressively kills apps since Android 11](https://dontkillmyapp.com/samsung) though.

Comment: @AndrewT  In this case, the option is there but grayed out and impossible to click.

Comment: you can downgrade ROM back to same bootloader level only